# What is the time complexity of JavaScript methods?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, big-o

Is there any resource to know the time complexity of natively defined array and string methods in JavaScript? 
I have to do guess work while I am using them to solve algorithm, but I want to be sure about what is the time complexity of those functions?

Comment: Note that there isn't a single implementation, so there may be no single, simple answer.

Comment: The array methods have linear complexity - they just iterate the array. There is nothing specified about string method complexity, as those very much depend on the internal implementation of string values and the applied optimisations.

Answer (score 2):

This question has been answered previously:

[Time Complexity for Javascript Methods in V8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622248/time-complexity-for-javascript-methods-in-v8)

In short, it's not specified and the time complexity for common JS methods can differ between browsers.

Worse yet, some methods might not even exist or will behave differently between different browsers and browser versions!