# Time complexity of slice in javascript v8 runtime

Tags: javascript, time-complexity, slice, v8

As per MDN

> The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array

That means you could effectively just return the pointer to the starting index in `O(1)` time complexity. But in many discussions, I see `O(n)` specified (linked below).

Links:

- [JavaScript runtime complexity of Array functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22614237/javascript-runtime-complexity-of-array-functions/22615787#22615787)
- [Time Complexity for Javascript Methods in V8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622248/time-complexity-for-javascript-methods-in-v8)

Was taking a look into v8 implementation but didn't get it. 
https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/4.3.49/src/string.js?autodive=0%2F%2F

Comment: Well, that's a 10-year-old version of v8 for one, and if you're looking for Array::slice, I doubt string.js is the place to look.

Comment: Besides - why don't you measure it? Run a benchmark that takes various-length slices from an array (and do something with those slices too); if they all finish equally quickly, it's probably O(1)...

Comment: @AKX Shouldn't string and array methods act similarly in terms of time complexity?

Comment: What makes you think that? There are many ways to implement arrays and many ways to implement strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(V8 developer here.)

`Array.prototype.slice` is O(n), where `n` is the number of elements in the slice.
`String.prototype.slice` is O(1), thanks to our implementation of `SlicedStrings`, which are just storing pointer, offset, length to the original string and avoid copying the characters (except when they're tiny, so that copying a handful of characters is actually cheaper and smaller than storing a reference; that's still O(1)).

The key difference is that strings are immutable, and arrays are not. When you do `str1 = "Hello World"; str2 = str1.slice(2, 5);`, since there is no way to modify `str1`'s contents afterwards, `str2` doesn't need to ensure that it's unaffected by any such modification.
When you do `a = [1, 2, 3, 4]; b = a.slice(1, 3); a[1] = "changed"; console.log(b[0]);`, then you expect to see `2`, not `"changed"`. That's why `b` has to be an actual copy. (In theory, a copy-on-write approach would be possible, but V8 doesn't do that for array slices.)

"Shallow copy" means that *nested* objects will not be copied. Example:

```
let nested = {property: "value"};
var a = [nested];
var b = a.slice(0, 1);
a[0].property = "new value";
console.log(a === b);          // false, `b` is a copy
console.log(a[0] === b[0]);    // true, `nested` was not copied
console.log(b[0] === nested);  // true
console.log(b[0].property);    // "new value"
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my read (which is to say, I could be wrong, since V8 is a complicated beast) of [this `array-slice.tq`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/refs/heads/main/src/builtins/array-slice.tq) source code, the answer is: "it depends".

If possible (and the heuristics as to when that might happen I didn't really get to), V8 optimizes things to essentially O(1) by just returning a copy-on-write view to the original array via [`ExtractFastJSArray`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/refs/heads/main/src/builtins/builtins-array-gen.cc#465).

When that fails, V8 allocates a new array and copies object (pointers) over, which is of course O(N).

The tq source code includes lots of "gotcha" cases, since JavaScript does allow you to call `Array.prototype.slice()` on things that aren't really arrays.